# Нужна помощь с Dagger2

Tags: java, android, android-room, dagger

Начал изучать Dagger2 и пытаюсь создать зависимости с Room.
Это компонент  AppComponent.

```
@Component(dependencies = {}, modules = {DataBaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Это модуль,где я получаю контекст,создаю бд, и предоставляю "сущности".

```
public class DataBaseModule {

    private Context context;;

    @Inject
    public DataBaseModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public AppDataBase getDataBase() {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context
                , AppDataBase.class, "database")
                .build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public CategoryDao getCategoryDao(AppDataBase db) {
        return db.categoryDao();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public ExpensesDao getExpensesDao(AppDataBase db) {
        return db.spendingDao();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public FinPlanDao getFinPlanDao(AppDataBase db) {
        return db.finPlanDao();
    }


}
```

Класс App где я собираю компонент.Он указан в манифесте.

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static AppComponent mApplicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().dataBaseModule(new DataBaseModule(this)).build();
    }

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return mApplicationComponent;
    }

}
```

И activity, где я бы хотел получить модуль

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Inject
    DataBaseModule dataBaseModule;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        App.getComponent().inject(this);
}
```

При сборке падает ошибка:

```
error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить подробно, что я делаю не правильно и как быть с контекстом.

Comment: а зачем вам получать модуль? удалите в активити `@Inject DataBaseModule dataBaseModule;`  и сделайте как я говорил в предыдущем вопросе. Ещё вы вы пропустили `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` в `onCreate` активити

Comment: @IR42 Я забыл скопировать конструктор.Не могли бы вы снова написать ваше решение( Ваш комментарий куда-то пропал с прошлого вопроса) .На сколько я помню, вы предложили собирать компонент в MainActivity, а не в классе App. Как тогда быть,если бы я хотел получать модуль и других классах,предоставляя им доступ через перегрузку inject в компоненте AppComponent? Спасибо за ваше терпение и ответ = )

Comment: @IR42 Как в таком случае я смогу получить доступ к бд,не получая при этом  модуля?

Comment: Решение в ответе предыдущего вопроса. Инжектить в активити вам нужно не модуль, а базу данных `@Inject AppDataBase appDataBase;`, либо `Dao`, но тогда для них нужно написать @Provides методы в модуле

Comment: @IR42 Ура, я понял. Спасибо вам огромное.